# how create UIbutton with Image and action in footer of UItableView?

Tags: iphone

I want to create a button in uitableView's footer section, which open new url when click on that button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any UIView can be the footer view for a section. Create a UIButton (a subclass of UIView), set it to be the footerView. Make an action that opens a UIWebView.